# Firefox is not being upgraded anymore

Tags: apt, 20.04, firefox

Running `sudo apt upgrade firefox` gives me:

```
firefox is already the newest version (75.0+build3-0ubuntu1).
```

While the latest version [Firefox 81](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/releases/) has already been released. Has any thing changed about Firefox after version 75 on Ubuntu 20.04?

```
$ apt policy firefox
firefox:
  Installed: 75.0+build3-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 75.0+build3-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 75.0+build3-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: Try to run `sudo apt update` before upgrading.

Comment: @adazem009 Already done.

Comment: is `focal-updates` and `focal-security` active? If so show us `sudo apt update`

Comment: please add the output of `apt policy firefox` to your question

Comment: @OrganicMarble updated.

Comment: The updates and security repos are not in your sources list, so you are not getting any updates.

Comment: @OrganicMarble It's odd. I've added them to `sources.list`. Now after deleting `sources.list` then running `apt update` and re-creating the file, then `apt update` again, it's solved.

Comment: I am not currently in a position to write an answer, but to fix this, you need to return `/etc/apt/sources.list` to its original configuration. There are many questions on this site about how to do that.

Comment: I am glad you got it sorted!

Comment: @OrganicMarble Thanks.